# jqGrid Columns reordering but not saving the order

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I'm using the column reordering feature in jqGrid which is working fine:

```
$grid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    sortable:true,
    ...
});
```

But after reordering the columns, the order is not being saved?

Can any one help me? Is there any way to capture and update that sortable feature?

Comment: I don't believe this feature is part of jqGrid. You will most likely need to include jquery.cookie.js and add some logic to store your column order on drop.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `cookie` ([jquery Cookie](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)) OR use server-side script like ASP or PHP to store columns position in database or file.

Comment: html5 localStorage may also be an option